# ActiveRecord error converting rails app from Sqlite to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I moved my app from sqlite to postgresql so that I could use RGeo and PostGIS.  I deleted all the data in my database and started from scratch. Everything is working fine except one particular area of the site.  I have an association that links Tourstops and Venues that appears to be not working.  No code was modified in this area since the switch.  Unfortunately I'm still sort of new to rails and don't know enough to diagnose this error.

The error I'm getting is:

**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ToursController#show**

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer LINE 1: SELECT "venues".* FROM "venues" WHERE (1) LIMIT 1 ^ : SELECT "venues".* FROM "venues" WHERE (1) LIMIT 1

```
  def show
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])
    @tourstop = Venue.find_by(params[:id])
  end
```

Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo, but I don't think `find_by` is an actual ActiveRecord method (at least not with just an id as a parameter)

Comment: I don't really know enough to be sure, but it was working before the switch.  Also in the rails docs it has find_by here - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by :-/ Not sure why I used find_by here to begin with though..

Comment: Actually, maybe its a rails 4 thing?

Comment: Yes, but you need to pass the name of the column as the first parameter (id here I guess), or try with just 'find'

Comment: Rails4 allows you to [use find_by with a hash](http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4?view=asciicast) -> `Article.find_by({name: "Hello"`})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem, as stated in the comments, that you're using `find_by` without any :key in the hash

To be clear, ActiveRecord should be able to translate between SQLite & PGSQL, so the difference has to be with your use of the [ActiveRecord methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html):

---

**find**

Finds individual element by primary_key:

```
Model.find(id)
```

---

**find_by**

Finds by value other than primary_key:

```
Model.find_by name: "Rich"
Model.find_by({name: "Rich"})
```

Comment: Ah so I'm just missing the { } then?  I will try this. Thank you Rich and Antoine

Comment: Actually, had this in several places.  Most places didn't have Venue.find_by(params[:id]) but Venue.find_by(name: value) instead.  Adding the {} to those worked and converting the others to find(params[:id]) was the rest of the solution. I'm still curious why it worked before though.